# weight matrix dimension intuition in a neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have been following a course about neural networks in Coursera and came across this model:

[image]

I understand that the values of z1, z2 and so on are the values from the linear regression that will be put into an activation function. The problem that I have is when the author says that there should be one matrix of weights and a vector of the inputs, like this:

[image]

I know that the vector of Xs has a dimension of 3 x 1 because there are three inputs, but why the array of Ws is of dimensions 4 x 3?. I can deduct that it has four rows because those are the weights w1, w2, w3 and w4 that they correspond to each ones of the values of a1...a4, but what is inside that array? Its elements are something like:

```
w1T w1T w1T
w2T w2T w3T
... ?
```

so when I multiply by x1, for example, I will get:

```
w1Tx1+w1Tx2+w1Tx3=w1T(x1+x2+x3)=w1TX
```

I have think about it, but I cannot really get a grasp about what this array contains, even though I know that at the end I will have a vector of 4 x 1 that corresponds to the values of z. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

As a thumb rule, weight matrix has following dimensions :

- The number of rows must equal the number of neurons in the previous layer. (in this case previous layer is input layer). So 3
- The number of columns must match the number of neurons in the next layer. So 4.

Therefore weight matrix = (3X4). If you take the transpose, it becomes (4X3).

Comment: i think you should replace word "next" with "current layer for which we are deciding weight dimensions" i.e. :

**The number of columns must match the number of neurons in the current layer for which we are deciding weight dimensions i.e. Layer-1. So 4**

Answer (score 2):

Too late  to answer this , but hope it helps somebody .

so we know every input needs weight with it .
there are 3 inputs .
there are 4 neuron

```
1st neuron : x1 - w11
             x2 - w12 
             x3 - w13

similarly,
2nd neuron x1 - w21 
           x2 - w22
           x3 - w23

3 rd neuron x1 - w31 
            x2 - w32
            x3 - w33

4 th neuron x1 - w41
            x2 - w42
            x3 - w43
```

As we know for 1 unknown we require 1 equation -> 3x+4=12
for 2 unknown we require 2 equations -> 3x+4y=12 & 4x+3y=24
now there should be 3X4 = 12 linear equations only then we can solve for 12 unknown weights.

now we have a matrix that is 3X4 . but when we multiply it with a matrix of 3X1 , it will not happen , since the multiplicative rule states that matrix multiplication can only happen when matrix is of size
mxn X nxk = mxk

so we transform the weight matrix to 4x3 and input is 3x1
result in 4x1 matrix

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is `3x1`, then a weight matrix of size `Nx3` will give you a hidden layer with `N` units. In your case `N = 4` (see the network schematic). This follows from the fact that multiplying a `Nx3` matrix with a `3x1` vector gives a `Nx1` vector as output, hence, `N` hidden units.

Each row of the weight matrix defines the weights for a single hidden unit, so the scalar product of `w_1` and `x` (plus bias) gives `z_1`:

[image]

In the end, writing all quantities as vectors and matrices simply allows you to use succinct linear algebra notation:

[image]

where we assume that the activation is applied element-wise.

Comment: thank you @cheersmate, but I know from where the las formula came from. Actually, I am curious about what information does the array W contains. For example, in the case that I wrote, is it contains w1 repeated three times in the first row, w2 repeated three times in the second raw and so on?

Comment: Actually, you write individual weights with `^T` in your question, but that's a transpose which only makes sense for vectors: this already gives you a hint about what's going on. The notation in the sketch means just that: `w_1` is a vector with 3 (different) elements.

Comment: I've also updated the formula to explicitly show the scalar product and the individual elements of `w_i`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your course the vector represents features in column-major order, and the weight matrix `W` represents for 4 neurons each has 3 weight parameters in this way:

[image: Wxxx]

but in order to do the math, you should transpose it, that's why you use `W^T`