# Dimension of dense layer weight matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Please refer the attached image. I am going through a course, Introduction to TensorFlow in Python.  While constructing Neural Network,   **`weights1 = Variable(ones((3, 2)))`**. I don't get how the dimension of this weight1 matrix is determined? Especially the column value. Why is it **`2`**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the number of nodes you have in the first layer (3 nodes) and in the second layer (2 nodes). You goal is to calculate the input matrix for the next layer, in order to do so, you want to get the output dimensions of (1,2) - so you will be able to calculate the final layer and get the single result.

The formula for weight matrix's dimensions at layer l is

```
dim(W_l) = [N_(l), N_(l-1)]
```

W_l - Weights matrix
N_(l) - the number of nodes at layer l

The formula to calculate the next layer:

```
Z_(l+1) = activation(W_l*Z_(l) + b_l)
```

Z_(l) - the output for layer l
b_l - bias vector for layer l
W_l - weight matrix for layer l

Hope that shed some light

Comment: "You goal is to calculate the input matrix for the next layer, in order to do so, you want to get the output dimensions of (1,2)" - Can you please elaborate. What is the "next layer" here and why should output be (1,2). Also from the formula - What is (l-1) ?

Comment: For simplistic reasons, let’s say we have a network with 2 inputs and three outputs no hidden layer. If I wanted to calculate the final output layer I would have to do W_t*X + b. And the out put should be (3,1) when three is because the output layer consists of 3 outputs. In order to do so, you will need dimension to match - so weights will be (2,3) and X is (2,1) - because of the input vector. And now after the matrix calculation you are left with (3,1) exactly the desired output dimensions. 
l-1 is the number of nodes I layer “l-1”.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348647/weight-matrix-dimension-intuition-in-a-neural-network

This can be related for your problem

Comment: "so weights will be (2,3) and X is (2,1)" . This can't be multiplied as matrix. Is that a typo?  Again why should the output be (3,1). Sorry I am new to this. Need some time to cope up.

Comment: it is not a typo because we calculate W transpose and X so the actual calculation is (3,2) X (2,1) --> which gives the output (3,1). The desired output is (3,1) because in my example there are 3 outputs - (3,1) - 3 outputs on the final layer